# How to debug the Action M in FromEvent function of system.reactive?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am reading the source code of Captura, and found it a bit difficult to debug the action M (or maybe I didn't understand the reactive):

The FromEvent is to wrap c# event (AudioSource.DevicesUpdated) to a observable sequence.

The Observable sequence that contains data representations of invocations of the underlying .NET event.

```
readonly IObservable<Unit> _refreshObservable;
_refreshObservable = Observable.FromEvent(M => AudioSource.DevicesUpdated += M,
                M => AudioSource.DevicesUpdated -= M)
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
            
_refreshObservable
                .ObserveOnUIDispatcher()
                .Subscribe(M => Refresh());

public event Action DevicesUpdated;
```

But where is the definition of Action "M" and how to debug? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `M` is the argument of the `conversion` lambda that you passed as argument to the [`FromEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229241(v=vs.103)) operator. This argument is supplied by the Rx. You supply the lambda, and the Rx invokes your lambda with an argument `M` that creates internally. This argument represents a handler that your lambda should attach to an [`event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) delegate, and all this happens because the C# language imposes strict restrictions on what you can do with an `event` delegate (you can only apply the `+=` and `-=` operators to it). The name chosen for this argument is usually `h` (from **h**andler), not `M`.

An easy way to debug the observable is to pepper it with [`Do`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh228941(v=vs.103)) operators, like this:

```
_refreshObservable = Observable
    .FromEvent(h => AudioSource.DevicesUpdated += h, h => AudioSource.DevicesUpdated -= h)
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"DevicesUpdated original: {x}"))
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"DevicesUpdated throttled: {x}"));
```

Comment: Thanks, the M is what Rx creates internally, how Rx creates that handler? because the business is different. How Rx know the business and creates handler accordingly?

Comment: @JamesHao the `FromEvent` operator has various overloads. The simplest one has no generic type parameter, and accepts a lambda of type `Action<Action>`, with the argument of the lambda being an `Action`. So I guess that in your case the `DevicesUpdated` event is declared as `public event Action DevicesUpdated`. This is not the standard pattern for events. Most events normally are declared as `EventHandler`, not `Action`. In that case you should use the `FromEventPattern` operator instead of the `FromEvent`.

Comment: Just don't understand the Reactive, can it be rewrite as AudioSource.DevicesUpdated = Refresh(); when event occurs, call Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action(()=> Refresh());?

Comment: @JamesHao yes, if you are unfamiliar with Rx I would advise you to avoid using it for the time being. Quite a lot of studying is required before being able to use this library effectively.